# Chart not showing fist x/y tick (pgfplot)

Tags: pgfplots, charts

I want to draw a chart but the chart is missing the first x/y tick.

What do I have to do to make the first ticks visible?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the full code on overleaf, I hope this is ok:

https://www.overleaf.com/18688751pxczqpkbbkyg

Comment: Try `axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left` instead of `axis lines=middle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max' comment did solve my problem.

Added

```
axis x line=bottom,axis y line=left instead of axis lines=middle
```

instead of

```
axis lines=middle
```